# Pip install from archive

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I am trying to install Dtale in jupyter notebook. Due to the firewall restrictions, I cannot install it online. I tried to download the archive file `dtale-2.2.0.tar.gz` and ran this command inside the jupyter notes.

```
pip install <path>/dtale-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

This fails as it could not find pypandoc. Then I downloaded the `pypandoc-1.7.5.tar.gz` and ran

```
pip install <path>/pypandoc-1.7.5.tar.gz.
```

But this time I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/d2/04/08841501db81bceb7a86a98dea7c12b0185fcc69bfdf1aea266f727d1d7e/poetry_core-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I know the host is unreachable due to the firewall, that is the reason why I downloaded the package. Can someone guide me through how to install the packages from the .gz archive file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this error tells you that there is a pkg in dependencies that can NOT be downloaded.
its name is `poetry-core`, so you should download and install it manually.
here is a url for it: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/04/08841501db81bceb7a86a98dea7c12b0185fcc69bfdf1aea266f727d1d7e/poetry_core-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl

 in case you can't download it too due to your firewall, you can use VPN.
in case you can't do that either, then you can download it from this url:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/kpnfupmf5px84um/poetry_core-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/file

 I have downloaded and re-uploaded it

Comment: Thanks ibrahem, But it didnt work either. I used pip install to install the PoetryCore 1.0.8. But the same error persists. 
One thing in noted here is that the anaconda packages show poetryCore 1.0.3 installed, not the 1.0.8 version. I tried to install it using Conda insall and failed